# Dns server (resolver)

Tags: администрирование, dns

Задача:

Создать форвард-днс сервер. Если домен есть в базе, то вернуть адрес его, если нет, то получить адрес домена через 8.8.8.8

```
simple.domain 321.123.123.321
yandex.ru 12.21.12.21
```

На подобие локального файла hosts.

Просьба привести примеры линукс демонов для решения этой задачи.

Про bind знаю, к сожалению проблемы с конфигурацией.
Если можно то с примерами конфигурации. Просьба не просить погуглить т.к. гуглив я думал найти ответ именно здесь.

Comment: покажите ваш ``/etc/bind/named.conf.options``

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eLukTz3J

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto прочитал https://firstwiki.ru/index.php/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD_(DNS-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7_ISPmanager там говорят, что нужно редактировть named.conf, вопрос чем отличаются named.conf от named.conf.options

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-caching-or-forwarding-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04 и https://www.akadia.com/services/howto_forward_dns.html

Comment: Спасибо большое, вопрос можно считать закрытым.